# Spring boot @Value SPEL

Tags: spring

I want to inject property from .yml file. If property doesn`t exist or null I would like to inject default value
prop.yml

```
security:
  disable:

@Value("${security.disable ? security.disable : false}")
```

It work correctly but when I add `disable: true` it don`t read value and inject default value(false)

Answer (score 2):

With @Value you can use ':' for  specifying default value

```
    @Value("${security.disable:false}")
    private final Boolean propVal;
```

Or you can use @ConfigurationProperties("security") on a class with default value inside. It needs a bit more work to get done (mostly adding @EnableConfigurationProperties), but it's much cleaner imho.

```
    @ConfigurationProperties("security")
    public class SecurityProperties{
        @Getter @Setter
        private Boolean disable=false;
    }
```

Comment: It give you exception with my props.yml. If delete from prop.yml ```security:
  disable:``` it work, if define true or false it will work but I would like that it work in my case

Comment: Without exception message it's hard to say what happened. 
PS. Remember that if you have line `security.disable: ` in your yml, then this property is defined and its value is null. If this is the case spring won't use default value (false in your case). You have to either 1) write custom converter 2)use custom setter with @ConfigurationProperties.  3) remove the `security.disable:` line from your .yml. I would strongly advise option no 3 :)

Comment: Thank you! I think maybe any developer know better Spring& SPEL and give me better solution